# Помогите с регулярным выражением,

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида: "1) Решил за 30 сек. 2) Решил за 10 сек. 3) Решил за 15 сек."

Нужно с помощью replaceAll("регулярное выражение")  убрать все, кроме цифры со скобочкой, т.е, чтоб в итоге осталось "1) 2) 3)"

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Это не серсис помощи. Это сервис ответов на вопросы. Что конкретно не получается, я не понял. Как вы пытались решить эту проблему? Вы читали документацию по функции?

Answer (score -1):

По логике - это задача не замены, а извлечения подстрок. Его можно выполнить таким регулярным выражением:

```
/(?:^|\s)(\d+\))/
```

`^` - начало строки
`\s` - пробельный символ
`\d+` - числовой символ, один или более
`\)` - символ `)` буквально

Comment: `\b` можно убрать. Никчему оно тут. так-как цифра не буква, никакой ценности `\b` не несет тут. Без него будет работать точно также.

Comment: @And, Если входные данные ограничены теми что в вопросе, это верно. Но неверно если в одном из пунктов будет содержаться число в скобках (для того и добавлен `\b`, чтобы избежать лишних совпадений) - хотя я действительно ошибся, там должно быть `^|[^\(]`.

Comment: Блин, опять ошибся - уместнее будет `\s`... по крайней мере, вероятно что между пунктами будет пробел или перевод строки.